# PyQt5: changing windowsflag from WindowStaysOnBottomHint to WindowStaysOnTopHint

Tags: python, pyqt5, flags, stayontop

WindowStaysOnBottomHint is a default option when running the program.

```
class WindowClass(QWidget, form_class):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        flags = Qt.WindowFlags(Qt.Tool | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint)
        self.setWindowFlags(flags)
```

And I want it to change to WindowStaysOnTopHint with a button, however it is not working properly
This is what I have tried with clicking a menu option

```
        onTop.triggered.connect(lambda: self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowFlags(Qt.Tool | Qt.FramelessWindowHint  |Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint)))
        onTop.triggered.connect(lambda: self.show())
```

The code is just toggling the WindowStaysOnBottomHint instead of changing it to WindowStaysOnTopHint
There is no error displaying while running onTop.triggered.connect()

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Please take your time, try to explain yourself better, and also provide a valid [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.